# How do i show a polynomial in textview in Android

Tags: android, string, resources, textview

How do i show a polynomial in textview like the following

x<sup>3</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + x = c

in Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a spannable.

```
TextView textView;
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>3</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + x = c"));
```

An alternative would be to use UTF-8 together with a font capable of UTF-8 you could simply use the UTF-8 superscript chars. A table with the superscript chars could be found here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/ the direct link to the table with superscripts is: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags in your xml for doing that.
Have a look at this:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/28/quickly-add-superscript-subscript/